# Add Filter to extract rows where the timestamp falls in between yesterday at 4 AM and today at 3 AM in Cognos

Tags: db2, cognos, cognos-10

I am new to Cognos and I am trying to add a filter to a column that only allows rows that are in between Yesterday at 4 AM and today at 3 AM.  I have a working query in db2 but when I try to add it to the filter in Cognos I get a parsing error.  Also, I found in the properties that the data type for the column I am trying to filter to be Unknown (Unsupported) type.  I started off by creating two Data Item Expressions for each time frame I am trying to limit the data by.  But I got a parsing error on the first one:

```
[Presentation Layer].[Cr dtime]=timestamp(current date) - 1 day + 4 hour
```

This works in my db2 local test database but doesn't even compile in Cognos. I also tried casting the column into a timestamp but that isn't working either.  Any help is appreciated.  I also tried using the _add_days function but I still get a parsing error. Also sampling the column I get values that appear to be timestamps as this string: 2016-01-02T11:11:45.000000000

Eventually if I get the two filters working I expect the original filter to be close to this syntax:

[Presentation Layer].[Cr dtime] is between [Yesterday 4AM] AND [Today 3AM]

Comment: Your first step should be to find out why it's coming back as an unknown type in FM.  What data type is it in DB2?  I'm not a DB2 expert, but that's a  pretty funny looking timestamp. I don't think DB2 does ISO timestamps (think that's what you have there).  If that's a char/varchar field, you'll have replace the T with a single space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your filter:

```
[Presentation Layer].[Cr dtime] between
cast(_add_hours(_add_days(current_date,-1),4),timestamp) 
and 
cast(_add_hours(current_date,3),timestamp)
```

This works because *current_date* in Cognos does not have a time component. If you were to cast it directly to a *timestamp* type you would see the time part of the date as 12:00:00.000 AM, or midnight. Knowing this we can then simply add how much time after midnight we want, cast as a *timestamp* type and use this in the filter.